# How to exclude the numbers written in two cells in Apple's Numbers app?

Tags: numbers

Hopefully someone can help me as this has me stumped all afternoon!

I have a spreadsheet and I have two columns that are added up to get the average.  The formula i'm using is this:

`AVERAGE H2,I2`

I want to add columns B, C, D, E, F, G & J together - **skipping columns H and I (titled OR and RP).**

How can I do this?  I keep getting a syntax error in column K, which is supposed to be the total of B, C, D, E, F, G & J.

I have added a picture, so hopefully it will make more sense.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to add those columns row by row. If so, write

```
=SUM(B2:G2,J2)
```

in Cell K2 and then copy and paste it to the cells below.

Comment: Thank you so much, such an incredibly easy solution!!!   I was copying all of these complex things that I'd found online and nothing was working.  Stackexchange wont let me upvote you, but thank you again!

Comment: Good answer! I’ll upvote it :)